# delete files on ubuntu

Tags: files

[image: Files to delete]

Can someone delete the files in the ring on ubuntu 20.04?

What i tried:

```
sudo rm -r <file>
```

output:

```
rm: cannot remove <file>: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE:

```
ls /
```

output:

```
 bin     lost+found   srv
 boot    media       ''$'\360''(S'$'\364\320''U'
 cdrom   opt          sys
 dev     proc         tmp
 etc     redirfs      usr
 home    root         var
 lib     run         ''$'\310\360''w'$'\370\312''U'
 lib32   sbin
 lib64   snap
```

Comment: Please add output of `sudo ls /` command.

Comment: `sudo rm /*` should remove these files. DON'T ADD `-r`!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just start nautilus as root in order to have the right to delete the file.  In a terminal:

```
sudo nautilus
```

and then rightclick and select "move to trash". Remember to empty the trash before closing the window.

Comment: Never run `sudo nautilus`.

Comment: Why shouldn't i do it?

Comment: Why not? Can you explain?

Comment: When i write sudo nautilus and remove these files it solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you for help :)

Comment: sure. you should keep eye out on where these came from, though.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use Midnight Commander to do such things. It's an extremely useful tool, one you couldn't live without ;)

Use `sudo apt-get install mc` to install it.

(Also, it's much safer to run Midnigh Commander via sudo than Nautilus)

Comment: It's true that it are much safer than nautiles. So i voted it up